# How can I distort one picture to make it match the perspective grid of another?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, perspective, clipping-mask, distort

I am interested in adding shops to this image:

[image: Image 1]

It does not need to look perfect, but my main problem is matching the perspective and location (the street width is different). I want to use google street view and find some locations from where I can make the walls on the side have some shops for example. If I can make some sort of perspective grid, I would use it to paint in the details.

How can I put the walls (and side details such as products) on the bottom picture on the walls of the top picture? (ignore the bad crop, had to reduce image size)?

Keep in mind that the picture in the bottom is from a 3D photo, so it's possible to find a better angle.

[image: Image 2]

Comment: I know that place in the top image!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you could cut the marketplace items out of their background by using common background removal methods. They could be pasted to your empty street image as new layers. Applying Edit > Transform > Perspective to the clips could make them look like they somehow fit the perspective if you handled left and right sides separately.

Do not expect the result would fit in the corners of the buildings. You cannot move the items so that they are less covered by each other except by creating the hidden parts by yourself.

To make the clipping possible the images should have 500% bigger pixel resolutions than your current attachments have and the needed amount of work to draw the needed clipping paths would be colossal.

But the result would be still wrong. Applying perspective transformation creates right looking results only if the real 3D shape is near enough a plane. The market items have width and height. Perspective transformation would distort them. The items would look right only if you pasted them as is. But the they would not be placed along the sides of the empty street.

A way to fill the empty street with a market plausibly is to get already fitting market scene  and paste it to the new background.

Getting the light right is another big challenge. It must fit as well as the geometry.

Another way is to get a massive amount of separate item photos and layer them on the empty street. Pasting the items from one side of the street at a time+distorting the perspective can be good enough for the distant part where the exact forms are not so important. That photomontage idea is already suggested by others.

The 3rd idea is to paste the sides of the market street, distort the perspective and use the bad looking result only as a reference of what items there should be. The final items would be drawn in right perspective manually. It would look artificial but it could be used to present the market.

Comment: Realistically though its less work and cheaper to reshoot properly. Even if it means hiring a local professional to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Elementary you can not. Which means not easily and not with vanilla Photoshop tools.

Although, advanced AI tools exist for estimating depth map from one image. I suspect it wont wont work well in this case and in any-case this is somewhat bleeding edge tech.

Comment: That's probably aside from the fact that the street is perhaps 400m long & the market no more than 60…. on a different lens, from a different height...

Comment: And the walls have different heights in the two images and the streets have different width. But a 100% old-school manual collage might be possible ...

Comment: @Wolff im not disputing it cant be done. But if someone asks how to do this then they are too many questions away from doing it to be helped. Anyway there exist research software that do this with 3 clicks though. So i expect this will be common 15 years form now.